# Difference between SUM and + when using times

Tags: excel

In Office 365 Excel, I have a spreadsheet with various columns, including one with times in, for example:

```
00:01:39
00:00:32
00:00:44
00:03:10
```

I have checked they are in "Time" format. I can add them using `+`. For example with the formula `=M1 + M2 + M3 + M4` but if I use `SUM`, for instance `=SUM(M1:M4)` I get a sum of zero (in time format).

I am not sure I understand why the two formulae should give different answers. I want to construct a `SUMIF` so would like to be able to use `SUM` here rather than just manually adding them up. What is going wrong?

Comment: I tried and I get "0:06:05" for both.

Comment: @Dominique - Change a column's cell format to Text instead of General then paste the values in and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dealing with text that look like time values¹ (numbers).

If you involve text-that-looks-like-numbers in a mathematical operation, there is a conversion to true numbers handled by Excel's overhead.

The worksheet's SUM function is designed to skip over text values so that columns of mixed numbers and text can be totaled without the text causing an error. As such, there is no implicit conversion to true numbers.

This can be easily demonstrated with the following.

```
="1"+"2"+"3"+"4"              'equals 10
=SUM("1", "2", "3", "4")      'equals zero
```

To convert a long column of text-that-looks-like-time to true time, change the column's format to General then use Data, Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Finish. You might have to restore the time format (Ctrl+1).

You can also force conversion using a function that does not share SUM's ability to skip over text values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--M1:M4)
```

The `--`` is called a double unary and forces a maths operation on each cell in the range by flipping the sign (positive to negative or negative to positive) and then back again.

---

¹ <sub>a) By default, times, dates and numbers will be right-aligned in a cell. Text will be left-aligned.
   b) If `00:01:39` is shown in the cell, `12:01:39 AM` will show in the formula bar for true 
        time. Text-that-looks-like-time will look the same.
   c) Changing the number format of true time will change the way the time looks in the cell.
        Text-that-looks-like-time will not change.</sub>

Comment: Also check the `Evaluate Formula` on both - `SUM` does it in one step, `+` does it in 7.  Not sure of significance by `SUM` returns `0:06:05` and `+` returns `00:06:05` - two 0's for hours rather than 1.

Comment: `hh:mm:ss` was the original time format of the values to be totaled and the overhead 'borrows' from that (again due to overhead). The SUM function reverts to your regional time format (`h:mm:ss`).

Comment: Ah, so just checking I have understood, what you are saying is that even though I have set the format to "time" it is still text. And presumably I could convert the text to numbers some other way (into another column?) and then it would be OK. I can't just select a column and say "make this time".

Comment: a) yes, the values are text, not true time. b) no. use the TextToColumns method I mentioned above on the same column.

Comment: Thanks. I used TIMEVALUE instead, but this solves my problem.